# a license agreement that is automatically terminated in practice

Tags: contract-law, licensing

When I read the license agreement of my samsung cell phone, I noticed that **lending** the phone's software (its OS) is prohibited. Also according to the license agreement, it is *automatically terminated* if any term of it is violated. But in practice one may lend the phone temporarily to let someone watch a video, play a game or have an emergency call. According to the agreement after such lending, it is illegal to use the phone because the software is lent and the agreement is violated and the phone cannot be used without using its software.

How can one deal with such easily terminating license agreement?

Comment: Buy a different device.  (Of-course, in practice if you live in a civilised country with fair consumer protection clauses, that clause would not be enforceable anyway - if indeed the clause is read the way you would have us understand it).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is what they meant by "lending the phone's software." Lending the physical device to someone is not the same as temporarily copying the software to somewhere else.

Besides that, can you post the exact quote that says that the entire agreement is terminated if any term is violated? Usually license agreements say the exact opposite - something like, "even if one term of this contract is found to be unenforceable, all other terms still apply."

Comment: It includes such sentence.

Comment: the contract is very similar to this one: http://store.apple.com/Catalog/US/Images/Appleworks6.htm which has the same problem.

Comment: I think what you are confused about is the sentence "Your rights under this License will terminate automatically without notice from Apple if you fail to comply with any term(s) of this License." It does *not* say that the license is terminated if you violate it. It only says that you lose any rights given to you by the license if you violate it. In fact, the license you linked to says what I mentioned above: "If for any reason a court of competent jurisdiction finds any provision, or portion thereof, to be unenforceable, the remainder of this License shall continue in full force and effect."

Comment: The bottom line is still that you are not interpreting "lending software" correctly. I do not believe the intent was to refer to borrowing the entire device (they probably would've written "lending the phone" if that was what they meant).

Comment: when the rights is terminated. it means that I no longer can use the software and so the phone. what's the difference?  Lending the phone means that I give someone the software to use it. The contract does not say anything about how to interpret lending.

Comment: If you feel that the terms of the agreement are unreasonable, your remedy is to not buy it.